# How to remove objects from an array within a mongoose model

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to remove multiple objects that are in an array in mongoose. My Workout model look like this:

```js
{
  _id: 5e04068491a2d433007026cd,
  exercises: [
     { _id: 5e0401b9dda7ea28a70e99ed, reps: '1', sets: '3' },
     { _id: 5e0401cadda7ea28a70e99ee, reps: '1', sets: '3' },
     { _id: 5e0401dbdda7ea28a70e99ef, reps: '1', sets: '3' }
   ]
}
```

I have an array of id's, named deletedExercises, these are the ids of the objects that I want removed from the exercise list. I am trying to loop through deletedExercise and remove any exercises that match the id of the deletedExercise item.

```js
router.put("/:workoutId", (req, res)=>{
  deletedOnes = req.body.exerciseId
    deletedExercises = []
    if(typeof deletedOnes === 'object'){
        deletedOnes.forEach(item => {
            deletedExercises.push(item)
        })
    } else {
        deletedExercises.push(deletedOnes)
    }
    deletedExercises.forEach(item => {
      Workout.findByIdAndUpdate( req.params.workoutId, 
        { $pull: { exercises: { _id: item} } } )
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply delete exercises using the `$in` operator inside `$pull` like this:

```js
router.put("/:workoutId", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.exerciseId); //[ '5e05c5306e964f0a549469b8', '5e05c5306e964f0a549469b6' ]

  Workout.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.workoutId,
    {
      $pull: {
        exercises: {
          _id: {$in: req.body.exerciseId}
        }
      }
    },
    { new: true }
  )
    .then(doc => {
      res.send(doc);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("Error");
    });
});
```

Let's say we have this workout with 3 exercises:

```
{
    "_id": "5e05c5306e964f0a549469b5",
    "exercises": [
        {
            "_id": "5e05c5306e964f0a549469b8",
            "reps": 8,
            "sets": 4
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e05c5306e964f0a549469b7",
            "reps": 10,
            "sets": 3
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e05c5306e964f0a549469b6",
            "reps": 12,
            "sets": 2
        }
    ],
}
```

If we want to remove the exercises `5e05c5306e964f0a549469b8` and `5e05c5306e964f0a549469b6` for this `5e05c5306e964f0a549469b5` workout, we can send a PUT request with this body: (url must end something like this `http://.../5e05c5306e964f0a549469b5`)

```
{
    "exerciseId": [
        "5e05c5306e964f0a549469b8",
        "5e05c5306e964f0a549469b6"
    ]
}
```

The response will be:

```
{
    "_id": "5e05c5306e964f0a549469b5",
    "exercises": [
        {
            "_id": "5e05c5306e964f0a549469b7",
            "reps": 10,
            "sets": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Wow that was a lot simpler than I was making it. thanks for the clear and well structured answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell considering you're not saying what error you are getting, but my guess from looking at it is that you are comparing an `ObjectId` with a `String`, try to replace this line:

```
{ $pull: { exercises: { _id: item} } } )
```

with this:

```
{ $pull: { exercises: { _id: new ObjectId(item)} } } )
```

** EDIT **

you probably need to also convert the main ID you are searching for to an `ObjectId`:

```
Workout.findByIdAndUpdate( new ObjectId(req.params.workoutId), 
    { $pull: { exercises: { _id: new ObjectId(item)} } } )
```

Comment: Alright I'll try that, and I'm not getting any error, the items just dont get deleted, nothing happends

Comment: Your solution doesn't do anything either, the types of the id's are now both objects which is good but still nothing is being removed from the array